# Is it possible to make interfaces with BaseContract as a type in ethers.js?

Tags: ethers.js, typescript

Is it possible in ethers typescript to set a class variable to what object this functio would return? new ethers.`Contract(V2_FACTORY_ADDRESSES[ChainId.MAINNET], CONTRACTABI.uniswap.factory, ProviderSingleton.getWebSocket())`

Im setting the object to Contract in my class but im getting this type `"hardhat/internal/hardhat-network/stack-traces/model"` as the only type of Contract i can accesss in the system. Im thinking theres some sort of NPM tool i need to use that would expose it to me like typechain, but even when using that it didnt return the same type of contract.

My overall goal is to create an exchange class that would be able to access both the factory and router contract, and even further just be able to set a function up in the class called "getPair" which i would just call the appropriate contract....but i need to get passed this part first